# Sorting lists by a numerical value in each string

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to be able to sort a list of strings with each one containing a numerical value and a word.

```
lst = ["1 Make", "7 William", "35 In", "22 Collins's"]
```

Desired output:

```
["1 Make",  "7 William", "22 Collins's", "35 In"]
```

Using sorted(lst) I get:

```
["1 Make", "22 Collins's", "35 In", "7 William"]
```

Comment: `sorted` can take a `key` argument, which is a function applied to the elements of the list to determine the sorted order, i.e. the element `x` is sorted as if it were `key(x)`. Which leaves you to figure out what function to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
lst = ["1 Make", "7 William", "22 Collins's", "35 In"]

sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0]), reverse=True)

# ['35 In', "22 Collins's", '7 William', '1 Make']
```

Comment: Will work, though probably non-optimal for large sets